# ng-change function triggers twice a time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-option like below

```
  <label for="categoryName">گروه اصلی : </label>
      <select class="input" name="categoryName" id="categoryName"
       data-ng-model="vm.mainCategory"
       data-ng-change="vm.changeMainCategory(vm.mainCategory.ID)"
       data-ng-options="category.CATEGORY_NAME for category in vm.allMainCategory">

       <option value=""></option>
     </select>

  <label for="subCategory" >زیر گروه :</label>
       <select name="subCategory" id="subCategory"
         data-ng-model="vm.subCategory"
         data-ng-change="vm.changeSubCategory(vm.subCategory)"
         data-ng-options="subCategory.CATEGORY_NAME for subCategory in vm.subCategory">   
          <option value=""></option>
       </select>
```

when i click on the second combobox the ng-change function triggers twice
what can I do to prevent from happening???

I couldn't add the main code but the short form off that is here
https://plnkr.co/edit/0uI4d1hqcRQCIe5GrAx8

Comment: Can you add any fidle/plnkr?

Comment: What about using `$scope.$watch()` in your controller instead of ng-change ?

Comment: @Charleshaa I didn't test it , because I prefer to solve this problem , what is the reason of this happening??

Comment: the first dropdown change is not triggering twice ? please add a plunkr with your code

Comment: @NikhileshKV no just the second one !!!

Comment: Welcome to AngularJS ! Haha.